Error when passing multiple accounts using the typescript program namespace
Object literal may only specify known properties and 'vestingAccount' does not exist in type 'ResolvedAccounts<{ name: "signer"; writable: true; signer: true; } | { name: "vestingAccount"; writable: true; pda: { seeds: [{ kind: "arg"; path: "companyName"; }]; }; } | { name: "mint"; } | { name: "treasuryTokenAccount"; writable: true; pda: { ...; }; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }>'.

The fix for this is just explicitly stating the account object but curious is there is a better solution:
 const accounts = {
    vestingAccount: vestingAccountAddress,
    treasuryAccount: treasuryAccountAddress,
    mint: new PublicKey(tokenMintAddress),
    tokenProgram: token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  };

  return program.methods
    .createVestingAccount(companyName)
    .accounts(accounts)
    .rpc();


A similar question and its answer can be found here: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/14345
Tip: You can press CTRL+Space (CMD+Space in macOS), in your code editor when your cursor is inside accounts({...}) call to easily see which accounts are required.

What if you do:
return program.methods.createVestingAccount(companyName).accountsPartial({"your accounts"}).rpc();
accountsPartial should let you specify all the accounts, while accounts will now "complain" about the resolvable ones
